# Inter-request signaling in GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, dropbox, gwt-rpc

I am currently developing a GWT/AppEngine application that uses the Java Dropbox API.
To pair with my user's Dropbox account I basically recover a URL to the Dropbox website that I need to forward my user to in order to authorize my app; the Dropbox website then redirects my user to a callback URL of my choice.

So I have my GWT app opening this website in a new window/iframe. However I want to be able to check when the user has authorized my app. So I was thinking of starting a GWT request that would only terminate when the callback URL is visited (that can be handled by a specific servlet).

Does that make sense? What is the "good way" of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On App Engine front end request are subject to a 60s deadline, so that wouldn't be the preferred solution.

If you really want to do the authorization flow in a new window/frame, you can consider communicating between the servlet handling the callback URL and your main application using JavaScript.

Alternatively you can redirect the user to the Dropbox authorization url, and set the callback url to your main application window.